# Check min version of compatibility of Android app

Tags: android

For an Android application, how can I test what the lowest version/API of Android it can work on, without manually changing API level on the emulator?

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: Do you have source code of the project?

Comment: do you have code or just trying to make SRS

Comment: in your app level gradle file see `minSdkVersion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minSdkVersion set in the app level gradle file is the lowest API version it will work on.

There are other factors though...for example:

Lets say the minSdkVersion is 21...but you call a method that wasnt introduced until api 25 (and dont handle that), then it will crash...and not really work.

Answer (score 0):

Open `build.gradle` of your `app` there should be written **minSdkVersion** which it supports.